# The status messages are not showing in my view

Tags: laravel, message, laravel-blade

I've a function in a controller function called `destroy_multiple` which deletes a certain element of the Database, with a certain conditions, for example if that element has a status **PUBLICADO** it cannot be deleted.

When this condition is true there is a specific  message that should show but instead this error page appears
[SQLSTATE[23000]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpYOV.png)

This is the code of my view

```
@if (session()->has('status'))
        <div class=" alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <p>{{ session('status') }}</p>
        </div>
@endif
```

My controller

```
public function destroy_multiple(Request $request)
{
    $eliminados=0;
    $enuso=0;
    $Status=Status::where('descripcion','Publicado')->first();

    //dd($request->codigos);

    //validar los datos
    $rules = [
        'cursos' => 'required'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
    }

    foreach ($request->cursos as $curso){
        $cursodb = Cursos::find($curso);
        if($cursodb->status_id != $Status->id){
            $cursodb->delete();
            $eliminados +=1;
        }
        else{
            $enuso =1;
        }
    }

    $texto='';
    if($eliminados>0){

        $texto = 'Se eliminaron '.$eliminados.' cursos con éxito';

        //Session::flash('status', 'Se eliminaron '.$eliminados.' códigos, sin embargo '.$enuso.' códigos no se eliminaron porque estan es uso');
    }
    else{
        $texto='No se eliminaron los cursos';
    }

    if($enuso > 0){
        $texto .=', '.$enuso.' cursos no se puede eliminar porque tienen un estatus de Publicado';
    }

    Session::flash('status', $texto);

    return redirect('cursos');
}
```

Comment: It fails on the $cursodb->delete() line, because foreign key check, that means there is something referencin the $cursodb->id in the database, that is why you cannot delete it.

Comment: Yeah I know but I want to  know why, instead of showing the the specific message that it's there, it shows me that error!

Answer (score 0):

It's your database schema that you set a foreign key constraint between two tables
"cursos" and that other table, using a foreign key "curso_id" 
and when deleting you didn't tell the schema to do anything, so you're violating your key constraint,
so you just should tell it to cascade or do nothing upon deletion in your migration file:-

```
Schema::create('other_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Some other fields...

    $table->integer('curso_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('curso_id')->references('id')->on('cursos')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

and it will work just fine.

or simply just remove the foreign key constraint and do it in your models files but notice when you delete you gotta do this manually:

```
DB::table('other_table')->where('curso_id', $curso->id  )->delete();
```

But the constraint is better than doing it manually, but you got to do it the right way.

Like here [Foreign Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#foreign-keys) but the last time they spoke of it was version 5.0 for some reason which i don't know.

Comment: So if I get this straight, the reason why that error is showing is, because I didn't contemplate the key constraint!

Comment: yea and it should work fine, but you need to refresh your migrations , try it